# Regex java : replaceAll whitespace except between hyphen

Tags: java, regex

I've got a string:

```
-----test test----- testestestest testestest -----test test-----
```

I'd like to replace each whitespace with `\n`, but I'd have to keep the whitespaces between the hyphens. Here is perfect result:

```
-----test test-----\ntestestestest\ntestestest\n-----test test-----
```

I've tried a lot of different regex but none of them work, here is my best try..

```
Pattern ws = Pattern.compile("\\s(?![\-]*\-)");
Matcher matcher = ws.matcher(myString);
String result = matcher.replaceAll("\n");
```

Could somebody help me?

*PS: What I really don't understand is that by replacing the hyphens with brackets (in the string as well as the regex), it works correctly...`\s(?![^\{]*\})`*

Comment: Not clear exactly what you want, but maybe something along the lines of `^(-.*[\s\S]+?-.*)|\n` replace with `$1`?

Comment: I've added some info, I'm trying your solution but not sure to understand

Answer (score 2):

Just match whitespace at the end of a line:

```
/\s$/
```

Here's the code:

```
String result = myString.replaceAll("(?m)\\s$", "\\\\n");
```

Result:

```
-----test test-----\n
testestestest\n
testestest\n
-----test test-----\n
```

That's in your code:

```
Pattern ws = Pattern.compile("\\s$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = ws.matcher(myString);
String result = matcher.replaceAll("\\\\n");
```

Comment: You probably want `\\s+` in case there is more than one trailing whitespace, and newline can be a literal, so: `replaceAll("(?m)\\s+$", "\n")`

Comment: @Bohemian That's true. I just read "each end of the line, there is a whitespace." literally. Same with the sample output and newlines. I find it unclear.

Comment: I understand your answer, but when it tries it doesn't work. I think the end of lines is not included in my original string, and it's just a graphic way to present it. Modified my post to be more specific

Comment: @mmcookie A generic solution for this is much more complicated. If there's always hyphens and something specific in-between, you could try to match something like `/-+[^-]+-+[^-]+\s/`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know there is always a single space at the end of 'every' line? If so, use this:

```
    String text = "-----test test----- ";
    text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1) + "\\n";
```

Comment: The string contains more than one line.